# what to write to add src to image?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to add src to the image for a long time, but nothing works for me =(
How to create js src for an image? Image tag and class are there, but its src is not?

```js
let child_block = document.querySelector('.child_block');

let xep = document.createElement('img');              
xep.className = 'img_s';
child_block.prepend(xep);
```

```css
body{
display:grid;
place-items:center;     
user-select:none;
}


.main_block{
display:grid;
place-items:center; 
border:1px solid black;
width: 50%;
height:500px;
margin:50px;

}

.img_s{
width:100%;
border:1px solid red;
}

.child_block{

width:50%;
height:50%;     
}
```

```html
<div class = "main_block">

<div class = "child_block">


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: should be `xep.src = ""` or `xep.setAttribute('src', <url>)`

Comment: Thank you =) What is the difference between them? what's better?

Comment: with setAttribute you can add any attribute to an element

Comment: Maybe second is more general ? Direct access may not work sometimes like aria-label, or for any non-standard (HTML) object properties.

Comment: which of these methods is better to use?

Comment: xep.src = "" might not work sometimes?

Comment: use `xep.src = ""`

Comment: Tom said that direct access might not work sometimes. What method did he mean?

Comment: attribute `src` is reserved for the `img` tag according to the `html` specification, so you can safely use the `src` attribute - `xep.src = ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `xep.src = "https://example.com"`